# CGImageSourceCreateWithData continues generate errors

Tags: ios, swift, cgimage

I'm facing an issue with my code. I can't seem to create an `CGImageSource`/`CGImageSourceRef`, however every repo that I see uses this exact same method. I've tested to see if the data object contains the `gif` and it does. So I've isolated this error to `CGImageSourceCreateWithData` function and I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the error:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

It keeps failing specifically with this function:

```
var imgSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, nil)
```

Here's my simple code that keeps failing:

```
import UIKit
import ImageIO
import MobileCoreServices
import AVFoundation    

class LCGIFImage: UIImage {

//MARK: Initializers

convenience override init?(contentsOfFile path: String) {
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: path)!)
    self.init(data: data!)
}

convenience override init?(data: NSData) {
    self.init(data: data, scale: 1.0)
}

override init?(data: NSData, scale: CGFloat) {
    var imgSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, nil)


    super.init(data: data, scale: scale)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

required convenience init(imageLiteral name: String) {
    fatalError("init(imageLiteral:) has not been implemented")
}
}



class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("1", withExtension: "gif")?.absoluteString as String!
    let test = LCGIFImage(contentsOfFile: path)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1", ofType: "gif")

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. But, the issue isn't with the path. It's able to locate the gif file. It's with the `CGImageSourceCreateWithData` function which keeps giving me the `warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the stack trace of your crash? I tried your code and the problem appears to be that the initializers are called recursively.

[image]

You call `super.init(data: data, scale: scale)`, which then calls `self.init(data: data)`, which calls your convenient initializer, which then calls your designated initializer, and this one calls `super.init(data: data, scale: scale)` again.

To be honest I would not subclass UIImage, there is a lot of bridging (which most likely involves magic) to CGImageRef involved under the hood. If you insist on subclassing UIImage make your designated initializer call `super.init(data: data)` instead of `super.init(data: data, scale: scale)`

Comment: This has worked. However, what confused me is that the same initialization pattern had worked in Swift 1.2, iOS 8, Xcode 6. Furthermore, correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't the UIImage not have a designated initializer? If so, [convenience inits delegate across while designated inits delegate upwards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID216). If so, the init pattern that I was following shouldn't fall into a recursive pattern.